# When click in dropdown item don't close dropdown

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4

Here is the Fiddle link for my code
I user bootstrap 4.
When I click in the dropdown, Dropdown will close in my local environment. In fiddle, it's working fine.
Which point I missing in my local. Even my local and fiddle setup are the same.

[JS Fiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/awesome_designer/8j3oLv9a/)

```
 <div class="dropdown d-inline-block">
                <button class="btn btn-info dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    Advance Filter
                </button>
                <div class="dropdown-menu pr-2 pl-2 advance-filter-dropdown" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
                    <div class="advance-filter-wrap">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="" class="sr-only">By Agent</label>
                                    <select name="" id="" class="form-control">
                                        <option value="agent1">Agent 1</option>
                                        <option value="agent2">Agent 2</option>
                                        <option value="agent3">Agent 3</option>
                                        <option value="agent4">Agent 4</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="" class="sr-only">Lead Potential</label>
                                    <select name="" id="" class="form-control">
                                        <option value="huge">Huge</option>
                                        <option value="medium">Medium</option>
                                        <option value="small">Small</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="advance-filter-footer text-right">
                        <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Reset All</button>
                        <button class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Apply</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: If it's working in fiddle and you have the same structure locally try different namings. Maybe there is a conflict with some other part in the page.

Comment: Nope, not working I already tried it.